# Detecting URLs with RegEx - how to prevent double-linking?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following to detect and replace links:

```
        // need to find anchors
        Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"((https?|ftp|file)\://|www.)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+(/[A-Za-z0-9\?\#\&\=;\+!'\(\)\*\-\._~%]*)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches = urlRx.Matches(source);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            source = source.Replace(match.Value, "<a  target=\"_blank\" href='" + match.Value + "'>" + match.Value + "</a>");
        }
```

however when `source` contains an anchor, this doesn't quite work because it replaces the innards of the already-existing anchor with another anchor.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Sample i/o:

```
http://www.google.com   ->   <a target="blank"> href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
Pre-existing anchors (<a></a>) -> unchanged
```

I think preventing matching any url preceded by a non-whitespace character (or quote `"`) would be valid, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Can you show one input and output example? are you talking about nested anchors here?

Comment: @Prajwal yeah that's right.  I want to prevent processing urls that are inside of a pre-existing anchor.

Comment: An example would be nice.

Comment: @Prajwal - just added details.  I think preventing matching any url preceded by a non-whitespace character would be valid, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: you can double check, right? check for source, if it starts from `<a` then don't do replace.

Comment: @Prajwal yes.  imagine I have a long string with many urls - some in anchors.  How do I modify the regex.

Comment: With a regex, it might look like [this](http://ideone.com/8tq3K1).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to check if there is already a pre-existing anchor

```
        Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"((https?|ftp|file)\://|www.)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+(/[A-Za-z0-9\?\#\&\=;\+!'\(\)\*\-\._~%]*)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches = urlRx.Matches(source);

        var rxAnchor = new Regex("<a [^>]*href=(?:'(?<href>.*?)')|(?:\"(?<href>.*?)\")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            List<string> urls = rxAnchor.Matches(source).OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["href"].Value).ToList();

            if (urls != null && urls.Count() > 0)
            {
                string urlToAppend = urls[0];
                // DO Your Stuff here
            }
            else
            {
                source = source.Replace(match.Value, "<a  target=\"_blank\" href='" + match.Value + "'>" + match.Value + "</a>");
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you wish to leave the pre-existing anchor as it is, then you can just directy check if the urls list has a count or not.

Comment: Thanks for this - though what about anchors that have other attributes - some may have `target`, some may have `class`, etc.  Can we just modify the regex to exclude any matches that are preceded by `"` or `'`?